# Simple toString() method

Tags: java

I am storing some simple strings to a vector, and I want to print each value on a new line and I am not sure how to do that. I am also wondering if it's possible to remove the brackets and the commas java puts in after it prints the vector? I know I need a toString() method, i am not sure how to write it.

Here is what it does now:

```
[Bob: Hello World, Bob: How are you?, Bob: I'm Good]
```

If possible I would like it to print :

```
Bob: Hello
Bob: How are you?
Bob: I'm Good
```

Comment: any reason you are using a Vector? I wouldnt use this unless you are using multiple threads.

Comment: Yea I am actually making a simple multi-threaded chat server in the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void printVector(Vector<?> vector){
    for (Object o : vector) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code should do it

```
public static String listStringByLines(Iterable<?> lst) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object elem: lst) {
        builder.append(elem.toString());
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This has the advantage of being reusable for many different types of enumerable objects and generic type parameters.

Comment: Why not just use wildcard generic in this case?

Comment: @DD. You are correct.  Fixed.  However, the Java compiler would still allow the caller to write `String s = listStringByLines(lst)` without specifying the type explicitly.

Comment: If you want to be platform-independent, you should use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: Java automatically takes care of newline conversions for text streams such as `PrintWriter` and `System.out`.  Calling `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is only necessary if you are planning on building a string, converting that string to an array of bytes, and then writing out those bytes to a binary stream rather than a text stream.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your Vector holds elements of type String:

```
Vector<String> yourVector = ...;
for (String line : yourVector) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Because OP writes: "I am storing some simple strings to a vector..."

Comment: I think @DD's point is that you could generalize even more and say: `Vector<?> yourVector = ...; for(Object line : yourVector) { System.out.println(line); }`

Comment: I'm not disagreeing... I just posted a quick and easy solution, perhaps at the expense of generality.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it yourself:

```
for (String string : stringVec) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```